# Show that the transform of a solution is equivalent to the transform of the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

The title is rather vague, I know - I'm struggling to understand this concept (let alone explain it succinctly) and would really appreciate some help.

I'm working through a pre-test for an exam tomorrow, and I'm stuck on how to prove this one - in class we've reached the beginning of the Invertible Matrix Theorem.

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $T : \mathbb R^m \to\mathbb R^k$ be a linear transformation. Show that if $v$ is a solution of $Ax = b$ then it is also a solution of $Bx = T(b)$ where $B = [T(a_1)\  T(a_2) \cdots T(a_n)]$ and $\{a_i\}$ are the columns of $A$.

So far, I've gathered that it will have something to do with the fact that the transform can be applied communally - I think - but I really can't even figure out a first step! What would you recommend - how do I prove this?

Comment: I maybe missing something but if $v$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ that mean that $C(A)_1\cdot v_1+C(A)_2\cdot v_2+\dots +C(A)_n\cdot v_n=b$ what does a solution for $Bx$ mean? to be in its span?

Comment: This is not a formal proof by any means, but it's what I've come up with so far:


If T is a linear transformation, it represents some matrix (hereby "C").  Ax=b, therefore Ax-b = 0.  T(Ax-b) = 0 = T(Ax)-T(b) = T(0) = 0,


T(Ax) = T(b), CAx = T(b), (CA)x = T(b), and (CA) = [C(a1), C(a2)... C(an)] = [T(a1), T(a2) ... T(an)] = B, Bx = T(b)